# Reading a Directory and Verifying if it exists Bash

Tags: bash, directory, location

I have checked everywhere and tried many different "Solutions" on checking to see if the directory exists. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Where is the directory/file located?"
read $DIRECTORY
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    echo "Exists!"
else
    echo "Does not exist!"
fi
```

What I am trying to do is have the user input a directory and for the script to check if it exists or not and return a result. This will ultimately tar/untar a directory. Regardless of whether the directory exists or not, it returns the answer "Does not exist!". (The input i'm trying is ~/Desktop, and from what I know that is 100% correct. Any concise answers are much appreciated :).

Comment: Instead of `read $DIRECTORY` use `read DIRECTORY`

Comment: Remove the $ on the first DIRECTORY (I.e. read DIRECTORY) and it should work. As is it isn't reading at all.

Comment: @anubhava, AFIK; what you said would be the problem. Would you put that as answer.

Comment: Interesting that [SpellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) doesn't consider this a syntax error.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, although it is almost always a semantic error. `foo=bar; read $foo` will set the value of a parameter named `bar`. Since `DIRECTORY` is probably not set already, and it isn't quoted, `read` doesn't get an argument and defaults to `REPLY`.

Comment: @BroSlow I used to use `read $var` for indirect assignment before `printf -v` (and `declare -g`) came along, but in this case the var's not set. Consider [filing a bug](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues?state=open).

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys and removing the $ from $DIRECTORY did nothing, but I happened to post this version of the script after changing many different things. Ultimately it seemed to be more of a file manager issue where it wouldn't let me use the tilde to search for an existing directory. Ex. "... directory?" /root/Desktop/dir-name rather than ~/Desktop which is quicker to enter into a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script can be refactored to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Where is the directory/file located?' dir
[[ -d "$dir" ]] && echo 'Exists!' || echo 'Does not exist!'
```

- Basically use `read var` instead of `read $var`
- Better not to use all caps variable names in BASH/shell
- Use single quotes while using `!` in BASH since it denotes a history event

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! Very concise and i like the format much more. For the first bullet, I did try that and to my dismay nothing worked as well as the second bullet (prior to your solution). See above comment for more of my reasoning as to why it didn't work (it might help if someone has a similar problem).